# Many to many relationship with Room resulting in Error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I am encountering the issue stated in the title. I have the following entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Person")
data class Person(@PrimaryKey var id: Int,
              var firstName: String,
              var surname: String,
              var age: Int,
              var numberOfHobbies: Int) {
    @Ignore
    constructor() : this(0, "", "", 0, 0)
}

@Entity(tableName = "Skill")
data class Skill(@PrimaryKey var id: Int,
             var skillName: String) {
    @Ignore
    constructor() : this(0, "")
}

@Entity(tableName = "PersonSkill")
data class PersonSkill(var personId: Int,
                   var skillId: Int) {
    @Ignore
    constructor() : this(0, 0)

    @field:PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

And the following relationships:

```
data class SkillWithPersons(
    @Embedded var skill: Skill = Skill(0, "UNKNOWN"),
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "skillId",
            entity = PersonSkill::class,
            projection = arrayOf("personId")
    ) var personIds: List<Int> = emptyList()
) {
      constructor() : this(Skill(0, "UNKNOWN"), emptyList())
 }

data class PersonWithSkills(
    @Embedded var person: Person = Person(0, "UNKNOWN", "UNKNOWN", 0, 0),
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "personId",
            entity = PersonSkill::class,
            projection = arrayOf("skillId")
    ) var skillIds: List<Int> = emptyList()
) {
      constructor(): this(Person(0, "UNKNOWN", "UNKNOWN", 0, 0), emptyList())
}
```

And I have tried everything, and yet it does not work. I keep getting the following error with kotlin-kapt:

```
e: error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
e: 

e:   Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
e:   Integer(int) : [value : null]
e:   Integer(java.lang.String) : [s : null]
e: error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
e: 

e: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

I am using the following versions:

Android Studio 3.0 with Gradle 4,
Room: `1.0.0-alpha9-1`,
Build tools: `26.0.2`,
Kotlin: `1.1.51`

It seems there's a bug with the use of `@Relation` as kotin-kapt seems to no handle it. Has anyone encountered this situation before? I have even tried to remove the `projection` from the `@Relation` but even that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried the same Room schema in Java and annotation processor instead of kapt?

Comment: Removing the `@Ignore` from default constructors got rid of the error for me.

Comment: @Virusman that doesn’t work for me

Answer (score 0):

@Relation Tag in Room right now only support one to Many relation ship as mentioned by "Florina Muntenescu" in her blog [post](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1)

Also for the above question make changes in your data classes as mentioned below

```
@Entity(tableName = "Person")
data class Person(@PrimaryKey 
                  var id: Int = 0,
                  var firstName: String = "",
                  var surname: String = "",
                  var age: Int = 0,
                  var numberOfHobbies: Int = 0)

@Entity(tableName = "Skill")
data class Skill(@PrimaryKey 
                 var id: Int = 0,
                 var skillName: String = "")

@Entity(tableName = "PersonSkill")
data class PersonSkill(@PrimaryKey 
                       var id: Int = 0
                       var personId: Int = 0,
                       var skillId: Int = 0)



data class SkillWithPersons(
    @Embedded 
    var skill: Skill? = null 
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "skillId",
            entity = PersonSkill::class,
            projection = arrayOf("personId")) 
            var personIds: List<Int> = ArrayList()
            )

data class PersonWithSkills(
    @Embedded 
    var person: Person? = null
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "personId",
            entity = PersonSkill::class,
            projection = arrayOf("skillId")) 
            var skillIds: List<Int> = ArrayList()
)
```

This way you can get rid of errors.